# NullPointerException when running configure.cmd for WebLogic Server 12c

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, server, weblogic12g

Context: I've been following this tutorial: http://saltnlight5.blogspot.com/2014/01/getting-started-with-weblogic-server.html which seemed simple enough so I began following the steps provided.

So I've got the WLS files unzipped to C:\dev\wls12130 and I type the following into my command prompt, and get the response found at the end:

```
> cd C:\dev\wls12130    

C:\dev\wls12130    

> cd .\user_projects\domains\mydomain    

C:\dev\wls12130\user_projects\domains\mydomain    

> configure.cmd
 **************************************************
 WebLogic Server 12g [12.1.3.0] Zip Configuration    

 MW_HOME:   C:\dev\wls12130
 JAVA_HOME: C:\apps\Java\JDK17~1.0_5
 **************************************************    

 Nothing to unpack    

 "ACLs are being setup for C:\dev\wls12130 Please wait..."    

CLASSPATH="C:\apps\Java\JDK17~1.0_5\lib\tools.jar;C:\dev\wls12130\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic_sp.jar;C:\dev\wl
s12130\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\dev\wls12130\oracle_common\modules\net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-0b3\l
ib\ant-contrib.jar;C:\dev\wls12130\wlserver\modules\features\oracle.wls.common.nodemanager_2.0.0.0.jar;"    

PATH=";C:\dev\wls12130\wlserver\server\native\win\x64;C:\dev\wls12130\wlserver\server\bin;C:\dev\wls12130\oracl
e_common\modules\org.apache.ant_1.9.2\bin;C:\apps\Java\JDK17~1.0_5\jre\bin;C:\apps\Java\JDK17~1.0_5\bin;C:\apps
\cmder\bin;C:\apps\cmder\vendor\msysgit\bin;C:\apps\cmder\vendor\msysgit\cmd;C:\apps\cmder\vendor\msysgit\share
\vim\vim74;C:\apps\cmder;C:\apps\cmder\vendor\CONEMU~1\ConEmu;C:\apps\cmder\vendor\CONEMU~1;C:\dev\wls12130;C:\
dev\PHANTO~1.8-W\PHANTO~1.8-W;C:\PROGRA~3\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\work\ECET\build\src\web;C:\PROGRA~2\SENCHA~1.
0-B\;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WINDOW~1\v1.0\;C:\apps\Java\JD
K17~1.0_5\bin;C:\apps\TORTOI~1\bin;C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\OPENCL~1\2.0\bin\x86;C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\OPENCL~1\2.0\bin\x6
4;C:\dev\APACHE~1.9\APACHE~1.9;C:\dev\APACHE~1.1-B\APACHE~1.1\bin;C:\dev\SlikSvn\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\nodejs\;C:\RUB
Y21~1\bin;C:\Users\brdegena\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\dev\wls12130\USER_P~1\domains\mydomain;C:\dev\wls12130\USER_
P~1\domains\mydomain;C:\dev\wls12130\USER_P~1\domains\mydomain;C:\dev\wls12130\wlserver\server\native\win\x64\o
ci920_8;C:\dev\apache-maven-3.2.1-bin\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin"    

Your environment has been set.    

> Do you want to configure a new domain? [Y/N]y
A subdirectory or file C:\dev\wls12130\user_projects\domains\mydomain already exists.
<Mar 10, 2015 1:17:24 PM MDT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling the CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity
 check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCE
Verification=true.>
<Mar 10, 2015 1:17:24 PM MDT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in R
SA CryptoJ from ECDRBG128 to FIPS186PRNG. To disable this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefau
ltPRNG=true.>
<Mar 10, 2015 1:17:24 PM MDT> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with Java HotSpot(
TM) 64-Bit Server VM Version 24.51-b03 from Oracle Corporation.>
<Mar 10, 2015 1:17:25 PM MDT> <Info> <Management> <BEA-140013> <C:\dev\wls12130\user_projects\domains\mydomain\
config not found>
<Mar 10, 2015 1:17:25 PM MDT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090065> <Getting boot identity from user.>
Enter username to boot WebLogic server:user
Enter password to boot WebLogic server:
For confirmation, please re-enter password required to boot WebLogic server:
<Mar 10, 2015 1:17:33 PM MDT> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141254> <Generating new domain directory in C:\dev\wls12
130\user_projects\domains\mydomain.>
<Mar 10, 2015 1:17:36 PM MDT> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000362> <Server failed. Reason:    

There are 1 nested errors:    

weblogic.management.ManagementException: Failure during domain creation
        at weblogic.management.internal.DomainGenerator.generateDefaultDomain(DomainGenerator.java:119)
        at weblogic.management.internal.DomainDirectoryService.start(DomainDirectoryService.java:108)
        at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:78)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1017)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:388)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:430)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)    

        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162
)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.ScriptExecutor.getAppSvcNodeByName(ScriptExecutor.java:3297)
        at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.ScriptExecutor.doSvcAssignmentByName(ScriptExecutor.java:4087)
        at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.ScriptExecutor.processAssignmentByName(ScriptExecutor.java:1961)
        at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.ScriptParserClassic$StateMachine.processAssignByName(ScriptParserClassi
c.java:1000)
        at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.ScriptParserClassic$StateMachine.processAssign(ScriptParserClassic.java
:902)
        at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.ScriptParserClassic$StateMachine.execute(ScriptParserClassic.java:453)
        at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.ScriptParserClassic.parseAndRun(ScriptParserClassic.java:148)
        at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.ScriptParserClassic.doExecute(ScriptParserClassic.java:110)
        at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.ScriptParser.execute(ScriptParser.java:72)
        at com.oracle.cie.domain.DomainInfoHelper.executeSilentScript(DomainInfoHelper.java:638)
        at com.oracle.cie.domain.DomainInfoHelper.createDefaultDomain(DomainInfoHelper.java:828)
        at com.oracle.cie.domain.DomainInfoHelper.createDefaultDomain(DomainInfoHelper.java:705)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at weblogic.management.internal.CIEDomainGenerator.generateDefaultDomain(CIEDomainGenerator.java:62)
        at weblogic.management.internal.DomainGenerator.generateDefaultDomain(DomainGenerator.java:114)
        ... 20 more    

>
<Mar 10, 2015 1:17:36 PM MDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FAILED.>
<Mar 10, 2015 1:17:36 PM MDT> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000383> <A critical service failed. The server will
 shut itself down.>
<Mar 10, 2015 1:17:36 PM MDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DO
WN.>
<Mar 10, 2015 1:17:36 PM MDT> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000238> <Shutdown has completed.>
```

I'm stumped at this point since the error seems to be internal to WL, which makes me think I'm missing some sort of configuration, but not sure what or where.

Any help is greatly appreciated, cheers, and thanks in advance.

Comment: I was able to get it running following the instructions here: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/wls_12c_netbeans_install/wls_12c_netbeans_install.html. I used the latest JDK 7 and WLS 12.1.3.